# How can I install tensorflow without internet?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to install tensorflow in my notebook.
However, wireless internet function of the notebook was broken.
I only can copy file from another desktop to the notebook using USB.

So, I copied Python install file from the desktop to the notebook.
I installed Python in the notebook.

And then, I installed tensorflow in the desktop.
And, I copied python folder(C:\user\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35) from the desktop to the notebook.
And I overwrited the folder in the notebook.

And I tried "import tensorflow as tf" in Python in the notebook.
However "ImportError: DLL load failed" occurred~

How can I tensorflow in my notebook without internet?

I use windows7, and want to install with native pip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [Tensorflow Install Instructions for Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) but with the following changes.

1)Instead of installing via pip on your networked machine, download the .whl file instead. You could try downloading a nightly from [here](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/DEVICE=cpu,OS=windows/) for example. Alternativley you can find where `pip install tensorflow` gets it's .whl file and download it separately.

2) Transfer this .whl file to your notebook
3) Go to the directory you put it in and run `pip install the-whl-filename.whl` This should install Tensorflow for you.

I would be careful with installing programs on one computer and transferring them over because you won't necessarily have everything including your system/environment variables and anything that sits in the registry. Just a warning that this may cause issues for you in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first you download Python 3.5.2 (correct version for notebook, *** confirm 32 or 64 bit ***), on the networked machine, and install on notebook. (not copy directory from networked machine).

You also will require the following dependencies on the notebook:

```
numpy, which is a numerical processing package that TensorFlow requires.
dev, which enables adding extensions to Python.
pip, which enables you to install and manage certain Python packages.
wheel, which enables you to manage Python compressed packages in the wheel (.whl) format.
```

With those in place (from JCooke's answer):

1)Instead of installing via pip on your networked machine, download the .whl file instead. You could try downloading a nightly from here for example. Alternativley you can find where **pip3** install tensorflow gets it's .whl file and download it separately.

2) Transfer this .whl file to your notebook 3) Go to the directory you put it in and run **pip3** install the-whl-filename.whl This should install Tensorflow for you.